# Wireless Printer Setup

Tags: drivers, software-installation, printing, canon

I am trying to setup my wireless Canon MX520 printer:

1. How do I obtain correct drivers for my Canon MX520 Wireless Printer?
2. Instructions for driver installation for Canon MX520?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you have?

Comment: In 14.10 (and perhaps earlier versions), the driver for MX520 is built in and can be selected from the Add Printer dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following easy steps:

- Hook your printer up to your router and give it a fixed IP address.
- Go to the dash and type `printers`
- Click on the icon
- Click on `<kbd>+</kbd> Add`
- (type your password if needed)
- Click on network printer
- Wait a bit
- Click on the Canon MX520 that now shows up.
- Click on <kbd>Forward</kbd>
- Click on "Canon" then <kbd>Forward</kbd>
- Click on "MX520" then <kbd>Forward</kbd>
- Click on "Apply"

### Done!

And as you seem to be a beginning Ubuntu user, here's some advice on **[How to install software on Ubuntu for the future ex-Windows user](https://askubuntu.com/a/575161/344926)**!  **;-)**